# How do I evaluate a variable with a string in the POSIX shell?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, docker, posix, test

I have a script that I am running inside a ubuntu container:

```
#!/bin/sh

name=$(cat < /etc/os-release | grep "^NAME" | cut -d "=" -f 2)

if [ $name = "Ubuntu" ] 
then 
  echo "This should return"
else  
  echo "This is wrong"
fi
```

I started the container by running:

```
docker run -it -v $(pwd):/scripts ubuntu:latest /bin/sh /scripts/test.sh
```

The output I am receiving is "This is wrong" which is not right because I know that the output of $name is "Ubuntu" because my laptop is Ubuntu but I can't find a reason as to why this is going down the else route in the script? It does the same thing on my laptop outside the container.

Comment: You're not taking into account the literal quotes around the string `"Ubuntu"`

Comment: Welcome! As a first step, please have a look at what [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) says about your script.

Answer (score 12):

The file `/etc/os-release` contains a list shell-compatible variable assignments.  You don't need to parse it from a shell script, you can just `source` (or `.`) it and use the relevant variables.

```sh
$ cat ex.sh
#!/bin/sh
. /etc/os-release
echo "$NAME"

$ ./ex.sh
Ubuntu
```

Answer (score 3):

On Debian, that particular line is

```
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
```

Note the quotes on the right hand side. If they are there on Ubuntu too, then you'll get literal quotes in `name`, too, since quotes aren't special to `cut`.
Another issue is that the string may contain whitespace, in which case word splitting hits on the unquoted variable expansion in `[ $name = "Ubuntu" ]`, and the test will likely give an error.

To avoid those issues, quote the variable expansion, and add the literal quotes on the comparison string:

```
if [ "$name" = '"Ubuntu"' ]; then ...
```

Or remove the quotes from the start and end of the string: `name=${name#\"}; name=${name%\"}`, and still quote `"$name"`.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, you could simplify your script as in:

```
#!/bin/sh

if grep -q Ubuntu /etc/os-release; then
  echo "This should return"
else
  echo "This is wrong"
fi
```

`grep`, when passed the `-q` option, will not print anything but exit with a code of 0 when the string is found, non-zero otherwise. That is what `if` expects, after all.

Answer (score 0):

Minimalistic

```
$ grep -q Ubuntu /etc/os-release && echo "This should return" || echo "This is wrong"
```

or

```
$ . /etc/os-release && echo "$NAME"
```

or you can use `lsb_release` command also

```
$ lsb_release -i -s
```