# Grep the RHS of the equal too sign

Tags: grep, wildcards, pattern-matching

I am grepping into /etc/os-release and then I want to store the output in a variable. I had made a conditional script where I was not needing a variable but now I need one.

```
[[ ${$(grep ID_LIKE /etc/os-release)#*=} == 'arch' ]] && echo this || echo something
```

The output of

```
grep ID_LIKE /etc/os-release
```

Looks like this

```
ID_LIKE=arch
```

I want to get the thing after equal to sign, what is the most efficient way to do that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I evaluate a variable with a string in the POSIX shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/596621/how-do-i-evaluate-a-variable-with-a-string-in-the-posix-shell) - same file, different variable

Comment: Wow, yes it does. Yeah I got this to work, But I would like to get better at grep. Can you tell me how to do this with grep?

Comment: Just `grep -q ID_LIKE=arch /etc/os-release && echo this || echo something`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the `os-release` manual on Ubuntu (`man os-release`), the format of the `/etc/os-release` or `/usr/lib/os-release` file is made in such a way that it should be safely sourced by a shell script.  When sourced, the file creates a number of shell variables, one of which you want to know the value of.

In a shell script, you could do the following:

```bsh
unset ID_LIKE

[ -f /usr/lib/os-release ] && . /usr/lib/os-release
[ -f /etc/os-release     ] && . /etc/os-release

if [ -n "$ID_LIKE" ]; then
    printf 'The ID_LIKE variable has the value "%s"\n' "$ID_LIKE"
else
    echo 'The ID_LIKE variable is empty, or not set' >&2
fi
```

This tries to source the `os-release` file both in `/usr/lib` and in `/etc`.  The  one in `/etc` should override whatever the one in `/usr/lib` says, so we source it last.

It then prints the value of the shell variable `ID_LIKE`.

I've added clearing of the `ID_LIKE` variable with `unset` first, as well as a manual check of the variable's value to detect instances where it is not actually set by either file.

Without these extra bells and whistles, the code would read

```bsh
[ -f /usr/lib/os-release ] && . /usr/lib/os-release
[ -f /etc/os-release     ] && . /etc/os-release

printf 'The ID_LIKE variable has the value "%s"\n' "$ID_LIKE"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var=$(grep ID_LIKE /etc/os-release)
var=${var#*=}
echo "$var"
```

debian